# create 'java.util.List' Frida

Tags: java, hook, frida

i create frida java.util.List

argument types : 'java.lang.String', 'java.util.List'

no accept error argument types do not match any of:

```
private List x = new ArrayList();

public String get_content(String str, List list)
```

my javascript code

```
hook.get_content("asdasd",[]);
```

i have another question

when I run the function from the library under a library
I get this error

cannot call instance method without an instance

Comment: We'd need to see more code.  I'm guessing that 'hook' hasn't been properly declared.

Comment: var hook = Java.use("com.android.m.a");
package com.android.m
a = class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frida doesn't cast Javascript array `[]` to java.util.List.

**Solution**:

```js
hook.get_content("asdasd", Java.use('java.util.ArrayList').$new());
```

An example of list with items

```js
var ArrayList = Java.use('java.util.ArrayList');
var items = ArrayList.$new();
items.add('a string');
hook.get_content("asdasd", arr);
```

For your second question

> cannot call instance method without an instance

take a look [here](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/272)

**Update:**

```js
hook.get_content("asdasd", Java.use('java.util.ArrayList').$new(), true, 1);
```

Comment: argument types do not match any of:\n\t.overload(\'java.lang.String\', \'java.util.List\', \'boolean\', \'java.lang.Integer\')
var str = Java.use("java.lang.String").$new("sdsadsadasd")
var ArrayList = Java.use('java.util.ArrayList');
var items = ArrayList.$new();
items.add('a string');
hook_.a(str,items,true,1);

Comment: @TolgaTaşçı share screen shot or full log in pastebin we can't understand it like that.. but it seems the method ur trying to hook has a signature with 4 parameters.. it's a very informative log.. take a look at my update

Answer (score -2):

Where is the declaration of 'hook' object ?
You can not use this object before you create it.

Comment: var hook = Java.use("com.android.m.a");

Comment: replace this [ ]  to x , as second parameter of get_content method.

Comment: how to get x veriable ? hook.x no get :(

Comment: Unable to access instance field without an instance

Comment: private List x = new ArrayList();

hook.get_content("asdasd",x);